# Azure create 40VM in parallel using ARM template

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I need to create 40VMs from an image connected to a single loadbalancer using ARM template. Is there a way to specify the count for the number of VM resource?

I am not looking for scale-set solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [copyIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#copyindex) function as `copyIndex(loopName, offset)`.

The following example shows a copy loop and the index value included in the name.

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyindex())]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[variables('numberOfInstances')]"
      },
```

For example, you can change the `variables('numberOfInstances')` to 40, and note that such resources like Azure VM name, osProfile, networkInterfaces should have unique name(include `copyIndex()`) in the following reference templates.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-internal-load-balancer